# VBA Excel Count Same Sheet Name Occurrences

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am working on a VBA macro and in one section I need it to count the number of spreadsheets but with a twist.  Some of the worksheets will have the same name and counted as sheet, sheet (1), sheet (2).  I need these sheets to be
counted as one group so the sheets will =3 instead of individually.

A simple example of the code I found to illustrate:

```
Sub aTest()

Dim myArray() As Variant, dict As Object
Dim i As Long, v As Variant
myArray=Array("Apple","Orange","Pineapple",
"Banana","Banana(1)","Apple","Banana(2)",
"Pineapple(1)","Pineapple(2)")
 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    If dict.exists(myArray(i)) Then
        dict.Item(myArray(i)) = dict.Item(myArray(i)) + 1
    Else
        dict.Add myArray(i), 1
    End If
Next i

For Each v In dict.keys
    MsgBox v & " " & dict.Item(v)
Next v

End Sub
```

Apples are counted as 2, and the orange as 1, but the bananas and pineapples
are counted individually instead of as a group.  What do I need to get the
count to ignore the "(#)" at the end of these sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the array item and check for a "(".  If you find it, drop that part of the text before you do the check itself.

This should do what you require.  Let me know if you need any further information.

```
Sub aTest()

Dim myArray() As Variant, dict As Object
Dim i As Long, v As Variant, bracketPos As Long

myArray = Array("Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple", "Banana", "Banana(1)",  _
            "Apple", "Banana(2)", "Pineapple(1)", "Pineapple(2)")
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    bracketPos = InStr(myArray(i), "(")
    If bracketPos > 0 Then
        myArray(i) = Left(myArray(i), bracketPos - 1)
    End If

    If dict.Exists(myArray(i)) Then
        dict.Item(myArray(i)) = dict.Item(myArray(i)) + 1
    Else
        dict.Add myArray(i), 1
    End If
Next i

For Each v In dict.keys
    Debug.Print v & " " & dict.Item(v)
Next v

End Sub
```

This produces the following output:

```
Apple 2
Orange 1
Pineapple 3
Banana 3
```

Comment: Thanks Dave!  "bracketPos"  was what I was looking for.  I knew there was some way to identify it, just couldn't think of it offhand.